# Automatically remap folder's contents to different drive when updated?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-management

I have a program that outputs data to a folder in my C drive (C:\Users\games\AppData\Roaming\Yernemm\OWET2\output). This program does not have a way to set the output path for it's data. Instead, I would like the contents to be automatically moved (if possible) after or during output to my portable drive (B:\output) so that i can save space on my boot SSD. Is there a way to do this in Windows 10?

TLDR: need to relink (remap?) folder's contents to a new drive, changing

```
C:\Users\games\AppData\Roaming\Yernemm\OWET2\output
```

to

```
B:\output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a directory link to specify this folder as being on `B:`
(which is not really a good drive-letter).

Move the contents if the folder to `B:\output` and delete
`C:\Users\games\AppData\Roaming\Yernemm\OWET2\output`.

The run CMD as Administrator and enter the following commands:

```
cd C:\Users\games\AppData\Roaming\Yernemm\OWET2
mklink /D output B:\output
```

(Add double-quotes if your names contain blanks.)

For more information on symbolic links see
[The Complete Guide to Creating Symbolic Links (aka Symlinks) on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).

Comment: Thanks a ton! ill write this here for future note but this was what i used...



`mklink /j "C:\Users\games\AppData\Roaming\Yernemm\OWET2\output" "B:\output"`

Answer (score 0):

These PowerShell commands navigate to the correct folder, remove any existing symbolic link that may be causing issues, and create a new symbolic link between the two folders.
for this purpose, the source folder is `B:\Github\stable-diffusion-webui\extensions`.

- Open PowerShell and navigate to the folder you want to put the link in by typing `cd B:\Github\stable-diffusion-webui-gradio-3-22` and pressing Enter.
- Run the following command to remove the existing symbolic link: `Remove-Item -Path "extensions" -Force`.
- Run the following command to create the new symbolic link: `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "extensions" -Target "B:\Github\stable-diffusion-webui\extensions"`.